# Strict aliasing violations in C and how to write conformant code?

Tags: c

The code seen below is typical of what is seen in some arena implementations. One such
example can be found [here](https://www.gingerbill.org/article/2019/02/08/memory-allocation-strategies-002/) (blog article on an example impl.).

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdint.h>
#include<stdalign.h>

struct thing {
  int a;
  int b;
};

char buffer[128];

int main () 
{
  
  uintptr_t p1 = (uintptr_t)buffer;
  if (p1 % alignof(struct thing)) return 1;

  struct thing *t1 = (void*)buffer;
  t1->a = 10;
  t1->b = 20;
  
  uintptr_t p2 = (uintptr_t)(buffer + sizeof(struct thing));
  if (p2 % alignof(struct thing)) return 1;

  struct thing *t2 = (void*)(buffer + sizeof(struct thing));
  t2->a = 30;
  t2->b = 40;
  

  printf("%d\n",t1->a);   
  printf("%d\n",t2->a);   

  return 0;
}
```

edited code: Made the program return 1 if any pointer lacks proper alignment

1. Is this an instance of a strict aliasing violation, and ...
2. Is the only way to place such structures in a buffer and to retrieve a safe to use pointer to the structure to do for example:

`struct thing *t1 = memcpy(buffer,&((struct thing){10,20}),sizeof(struct thing));`

Comment: I don't think there's a strict aliasing violation here, since there's no value that's being written with one type and read with another (incompatible) type.

Comment: @PaulHankin [But...](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.3p7) "A pointer to an object type may be converted to a pointer to a different object type. If the resulting pointer is not correctly aligned for the referenced type, the behavior is undefined."   Note that dereferencing the pointer is not necessary in order to invoke undefined behavior.  So `struct thing *t1 = (void*)buffer;` can invoke undefined behavior under C11 6.3.2.3p7 even though it's not a strict aliasing violation.

Comment: @AndrewHenle That's a good point, let's make it quit if it's not properly aligned for both cases

Comment: `if (p1 % alignof(struct thing)) return 1;` is a reasonable  test for alignment needs of `struct thing *t1 = (void*)buffer;`, but not a _specified_ sufficient test.  `struct thing *t1 = (void*)buffer; t1->a = 10;` remains potential UB.

Comment: "Is the only way..." --> Use a `union` amongst other choices.  Best approach relies on knowing more of the overall code needs.  Sample code too trivial.

Comment: @chux Indeed. The standard could really do with some sort of "is aligned" operation (amongst other things).

Answer (score 3):

> Is this an instance of a strict aliasing violation

Yes. `t1->a` etc access the character array through a different type than the "effective type" (`char`).

> Is the only way to place such structures in a buffer and to retrieve a safe to use pointer to the structure to do for example:

You can also create a union of a raw character array and the type you wish to convert to. Example:

```
typedef union
{
  struct thing t;
  char buf[128];
} strict_aliasing_hack;

...

strict_aliasing_hack thing t1 = *(strict_aliasing_hack*)buffer;
```

This is ok because `strict_aliasing_hack` is "an aggregate or union type that includes one a type compatible with the effective type of the object among its members" (C17 6.5/7).

Naturally, it is best to stay clear of fishy conversions like this entirely. For example the chunk of data returned from malloc has no effective type. So the original code is much better written as:

```
struct thing *t1 = malloc(128);
```

And now you can lvalue access `*t1` in any way you like.

Comment: How would this union technique work for placing two such structs in the buffer?

Comment: @anonymouscoward If overlapping, then simply add a 3rd member. If contiguous, then you'd have to invent a 3rd struct containing the others, then place that in the union. As per C11 we can also have anonymous structs, so you could write `struct { struct foo; struct bar; };` inside the union.

Comment: `(strict_aliasing_hack*)buffer;` is a problem as `strict_aliasing_hack` may have greater alignment needs than `char`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Sure but alignment is a different matter. The OP also added various tricks to ensure that wouldn't be the case in this example.

Comment: The problem if the bufffer is returned by the function reading for example external sensor,

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that *per standard* only dynamic memory can be used that way.

Clause 5 Expressions says (ref n1570 for C11):

> §6 The effective type of an object for an access to its stored value is the declared type of the object, if any.

If you use:

```
void * buffer = malloc(128);
```

then buffer is guaranteed to have an alignment compatible with any standard type **and has no declared type**.

In that case you can safely store a `thing` object in buffer without triggering any strict aliasing violation. But in your example code, `buffer` has a declared type which is `char`. Whatever the alignment, using a different type is then a strict aliasing violation.

Comment: Alternatively if I want to avoid malloc or memcpy, I would have to declare `extern void * buffer` and set it up through a linker script?

Comment: @anonymouscoward That's probably not a good idea for several other reasons. But yeah, areas of the memory where no variables were declared can be assumed to have "no effective type", since the compiler doesn't know of any variables declared there. That is, until the point where you write access that area. Memory-mapped hardware registers of an embedded system would be one such example.

Answer (score 1):

IMO memcpy is always the safest way. It will produce the optimized enough output for the particular platform.

```
typedef struct thing {
  int a;
  int b;
}thing;

int geta(const void *buff, const size_t offset)
{
    const unsigned char *chbuff = buff;
    thing t;

    memcpy(&t, chbuff + offset, sizeof(t));

    return t.a;
}

int geta1(const void *buff, const size_t offset)
{
    const unsigned char *chbuff = buff;
    int a;

    memcpy(&a, chbuff + offset + offsetof(thing, a), sizeof(a));

    return a;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/x8e96ezW9